# how can i setup tshark to capture full URL uri request ip and time stamp

Tags: ubuntu, wireshark, tshark

How can I setup **tshark** to capture full URL uri request ip and time stamp.

I have tried this:

```
tshark -V -R "tcp.port ==80 && (http.request || http.response)" | awk "/Hypertext Transfer Protocol/,/Frame/ { print };/Transmission Control Protocol/{print};/Internet Protocol/{print}" | grep -v Frame
```

Also I want to capture DNS requests with this.

Can I capture https URLs also with **tshark** or **wireshark**, like application data whatsapp, facebook app for android devices.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark (and tshark) uses different formats for describing display filters and capture filters. The one you are using is a display filter.

You can find more information on how to capture HTTP [here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Hyper_Text_Transfer_Protocol).